# Change localhost document root

Tags: localhost, wampserver

I have install wamp server on my computer and I need set the document root url on relative path. I need this shape of address URL:

// when I use document root directive `__DIR__` I want get output like bellow

// output

```
http://localhost/
```

Its possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a little confused. The `__DIR__` command does this ( from the manual )

```
The directory of the file. 
If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. 
This is equivalent to dirname(__FILE__). 
This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.
```

If you want a PHP syntax that will return you the DocumentRoot regardless of where it is called from use

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
```